# Trying to use react-image-gallery and I get "could not load the image" error even though the file path is definitely correct

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

I'm trying to learn React but frankly it's quite disheartening that I can't even get third-party libraries to work. I have the following code in my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const images = [
  {
  original: 'images\Doodle1.png',
  thumbnail: 'images\Doodle1=thumb.png'
  },
  {
    original: 'images\Doodle2.png',
    thumbnail: 'images\doodle2-thumb.png'
  },
  {
    original: 'images\Doodle3.png',
    thumbnail: 'images\Doodle3-thumb.png'
  },
  {
    original: 'images\Doodle4.png',
    thumbnail: 'images\Doodle4-thumb.png'
  },
  {
    original: 'images\Doodle5.png',
    thumbnail: 'images\Doodle5-thumb.png'
  }
];

class Art extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ImageGallery items={images} />;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    ReactDOM.render(<Art />, document.getElementById("root"))
  );
}





export default App;
```

Furthermore, when I try to render the image in the "Gallery" div on my index.html, I get the error that it is not a DOM node, when it most certainly is. However, the main problem I want to solve is why the images are not showing. For my App.css, I have only this line at the minute:

```
@import "~react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
```

If anyone can shed some light on the situation, I'd be massively grateful, as I feel like I'm bashing my head off a brick wall at the minute.

Comment: Please share folder structure. Try `./images/Doodle1.png`.

Comment: @Sandy I used the relative file path in visual studio code, shouldn't that work? I have the code files in website/src and the images in website/images

Answer (score 1):

all of your image paths are wrong instead of using `\` use `/`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything :/

Comment: try to locate you image in the path and then put it as a full path exm. `http://localhost/image/Doodle1.png`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comment, you have all `jsx` files in `website/src` and images in `website/images`. So no, your paths defined will not work.

First suggestion would be to place your images in `src` or `public` folder as react build (at least by `create-react-app`) uses these folders.

You must navigate to images folder using `../` and reach the correct path. Please share folder structure for accurate path.

[RelativePath](https://github.com/jakob101/RelativePath) extension maybe helpful on VS Code.

Hope it helps.